# Customize x-axis ticks to display range in a histogram?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

The following code below

```
library("ggplot2")
library("datasets")
data(iris)

iris.hist <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length)) +
                      geom_histogram(data = subset(iris, Species == "setosa"), bins = 5, fill = "black", color = "black") +
                      geom_histogram(data = subset(iris, Species == "versicolor"), bins = 5, fill = "white", color = "black")


iris.hist
```

generates the plot

[image]

As you can see, the x-axis shows ticks for the integers in the data range,  but these ticks do not necessarily reflect very well the real data range contained in each bin in this histogram.

Is there a way I could modify this script to allow the x-axis to show the real range of each bin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `breaks` instead of `bins`:

```r
mybreaks <- c(3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7, 7.5)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_histogram(data = subset(iris, Species == "setosa"), 
                 breaks = mybreaks, fill = "black", color = "black") +
  geom_histogram(data = subset(iris, Species == "versicolor"), 
                 breaks = mybreaks, fill = "white", color = "black") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = mybreaks)
```

[image]

Comment: Although the breaks is a better way to clearly define the bin ranges, this solution still doesn't fix the visual aspect of the histogram - the x-axis tick labels. I would like the plot to clearly show which range each bin represents.